# How to recover previous version of folder in Icloud drive?

Tags: icloud, revision

For some stupid reason, I managed to overwrite an existing folder with a symlink to another folder.
Is there any way that I can recover the original folder and contents?
I already looked into Icloud.com but can't find them in the Recover Files dialog